# How to add a social media icon in prestashop?

Tags: prestashop

i tried to add a social media icon and the link in prestashop from modules and to be more specific, i followed the path: modules -> modules and services -> installed modules -> social media follow links, inserted an instagram url, in instagram field, but nothing happened.
My question is, if anyone knows how can i add a social media icon, so when a customer click on it, it will connect him with instagram profile of E-shop.

The prestashop version is 1.7.5.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should appear in the footer near email subscription form if you use the default theme. If you use a custom theme check if the module is added to any of the hooks(by default it is hooked to `displayFooter`) you can do this by a path **Design->Positions** and try to find the module there. Also, do not forget to clean a cache if you did any change. Go to **Advanced Parameters->Performance** and click the button **Clear cache** in the right top corner. I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but i solved with another way. I followed the path: Layout Builder->Footer Builder->Edit Widget in Social Media Links and pasted instagram url!